# If a query result is inserted to a table, will it be automatically updated If I update the original table?

Tags: sql

If I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table A
```

And I insert the result into table `B`. If I update table `A` later, will table `B` be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The insert takes place once, when you execute it.

If you want something more dynamic, use a view:

```
create view v_b as
    select *
    from a;
```

Any changes to `a` are reflected in `b` when you query it.

Answer (score 0):

Only if A and B are related via a FOREIGN KEY constraint and **table B has UPDATE CASCADE enabled**